# Huffman tree - highest possible frequency that gives perfect tree

Tags: encoding, compression, theory, huffman-code

Suppose you have an alphabet of 4 characters: A, B, C, D. What is the highest possible frequency of the most frequent character given the Huffman tree is perfect.

We have a theory that it is 2/5 of the total length, but we would like to see more concrete proof or explanations.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138023/huffman-coding-conditions-for-perfect-tree-output) over on _math_ for a related discussion.

Comment: Define "perfect".

Comment: perfect: all leaves are the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we will assume that p(A) <= p(B) <= p(C) <= p(D). The Huffman algorithm will combine A and B into a branch. (Again, without loss of generality if some of the probabilities are equal.) In order for the resulting tree to be flat, we must then combine C and D into a branch. Then the final step will be to combine those two branches.

To assure that we combine C and D into a branch, p(C) and p(D) must both be less than p(A) + p(B). So **p(D) < p(A) + p(B)**. Note that if p(C) = p(D) = p(A) + p(B), then the Huffman algorithm has the option to pick any pair in the next step, for which two of those cases results in skewed tree. So p(D) must be strictly less than p(A) + p(B).

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

(Your guess is close. It must be *less* than 2/5. So 2/5–ϵ, where ϵ is the smallest number that allows the probability computed from the frequency, presumably an integer, to be less than 2/5. An example set of probabilities to reach the maximum is {1/5, 1/5, 1/5+ϵ, 2/5–ϵ}.)